# how to write a function using cin.fail() to ensure valid input in main?

Tags: c++, function, validation

Part of the requirement is that the function should not take any arguments.
But the problem is that where can I store the cin input? I got an infinite loop here.

```
double getValidDouble(){
    string invalid_input;
    while (cin.fail()){
        cout << "You entered a value of the wrong type!" << endl;
        getline(cin,invalid_input);
        cout << "Enter a double this time: " << endl;  
    }
}
```

Comment: I presume this is C++?

Comment: yes it is. Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm not totally following but why not just declare a local variable and return it?

```
double getValidDouble(){
    string invalid_input;
    double val;
    cin >> val;
    while (cin.fail()){
        cout << "You entered a value of the wrong type!" << endl;
        cin.clear();
        getline(cin,invalid_input);
        cout << "Enter a double this time: " << endl;  
        cin >> val;
    }
    return val;
}
```

Infinite loop is probably due to you not doing `cin.clear()` after the error.

Comment: instead, use `while (!(cin >> val))`

Comment: also, `istream::ignore` is more suited to this than `getline`.

Comment: @BenVoigt I agree about ignore, but on the other I think getline is more readily understood by beginners. As for fail, I got the impression that using it was a requirement of this exercise so I left it in.