# Why string receives numbers in this while loop?

Tags: c++, string

A string is a variable-length sequence of characters. 
 Why does it receive anything and prints it out?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main (){
    string word;
    while (cin >> word){
        cout << word << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In this program, we read into a string, not an int. How can I fall out of this while loop i.e hit an invalid input?

Comment: What would be considered "invalid input"?

Comment: I think your `while` loop will continue to execute so long as the `cin` operate is successful.  Entering a number should work, so it won't cause the loop to fail.  But an IO error would.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Why it receives numbers?

Comment: @MohamedMagdy -- A string takes any characters, including characters that represent digits.  If the string is "1234" or "Paul100", they are both valid strings.

Comment: I.e. (any number) considered a character?

Comment: @MohamedMagdy anything a user could possibly type is considered a character.

Comment: @MohamedMagdy -- Entering a string allows the user to type anything on the keyboard without any error at the time of inputting those characters.  What you probably want to do is take the entered string and figure out if the string entered passes some test of validity. You have to write that code to determine that, maybe call a function on the string, etc   It isn't automatic.

Comment: Everything is a string baby!

Comment: @DrewDormann I read this sample of code in c++ primer 5th edition, In this program, we read into a string, not an int. Otherwise, the while condition
executes similarly to the one in our previous program. The condition tests the stream
after the read completes. If the stream is valid—it hasn’t hit end-of-file or encountered
an invalid input—then the body of the while is executed. The body prints the value
we read on the standard output. Once we hit end-of-file (or invalid input), we fall out
of the while. <br> This phrase confuses me a bit (Once we hit (invalid input).

Comment: Any sequence of Unicode code-point is a valid string (probably wstring). `123` is just `49 50 51`.

Comment: @MohamedMagdy There is no invalid input when entering a string.  What could occur is while entering the string, you type a special combination of keys, for example in Windows, `Ctrl-Z` to halt the entering of the data and the input stops.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie OMG, Ctrl + Z stops the loop!

Comment: Possible duplicate: [how to write a function using cin.fail() to ensure valid input in main?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16378465/how-to-write-a-function-using-cin-fail-to-ensure-valid-input-in-main)

Comment: How can I set the fail bit on this question? `cin.fail()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading into a string will not fail, all input is valid. You may add any validation you like once the string is read.

Your question is a little vague, but if you're asking how to end the loop you can do it with an end-of-file. On Linux this you can generate one from the console with Control-D, and on Windows with Control-Z plus Enter.

Comment: Actually this is the answer I was looking forward.

Comment: @MohamedMagdy because your question was really vague.  Check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I didn't down vote you.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are taking the input in a string and string is a sequence of characters .so it takes anything you input from the keyboard either it is number or alphabet or any special character .

Answer (score 0):

> How can I check for invalid input?

If you could define what you consider to be "invalid input" you can filter for it in one of the `std::string` helper methods. In your example you eluded to numbers not being strings... so if you want to do something with pure numbers...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main (){
    string word;
    while (cin >> word){
        bool isNumber = (word.find_first_not_of("0123456789") == std::string::npos);
        if (isNumber){
            cout << "it's a number! " << word << endl;
        }else{ 
            cout << word << endl;
        } 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: (word.find_first_not_of("0123456789") == std::string::npos); What does this mean?

Comment: It searches through the string object for anything other than pure digits. If it gets to the end of the string without finding anything other than a digits, the boolean isNumber evaluates to true and you can convert it to an integer if you'd like.  See [string::find_first_not_of documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_not_of/) for more info.